# 'Flask' object has no attribute 'open_resourse'

Tags: flask

Всем добрый день, читаю туториал (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/) и не понимаю в чем ошибка:

```
with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'open_resourse'
```

мой код:

```
import sqlite3
import os
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
abort, render_template, flash
from contextlib import closing

DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'flaskr.db'),
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY='development key',
    USERNAME='admin',
    PASSWORD='default'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()

def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Делаю все как написано в туториале. Спасибо за советы.
P.S. Сис. Windows.

Comment: `import flask` `flask.__version__` какая у вас версия?

Comment: версия '0.12.2'

Comment: А из какого именно урока взяли код?

Comment: из: https://flask-russian-docs.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/tutorial/dbinit.html#tutorial-dbinit

Comment: Чего-то в вашем коде не хватает. Например проблема в `init_db`, но у вас эта функция не вызывается. Так-то я запускал ваш код и он отработал без проблем. Добавлял перед `app.run()` `init_db` и только ошибка `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ...` была, т.к. файл `sqlite_db` не существовал